Linux MTA for forwarding and/or autoreply only
I am looking for an MTA (running on Linux) to auto-reply and/or forward e-mail based on the e-mail address, and optionally the sender.
At the moment the current MTA (Postfix) is the destination of subdomain.domain.tld, but this domain will soon cease to exist. How can I set up an MTA (like Postfix, Exim) to do the following:

If there is an email sent to important@subdomain.domain.tld, and the sender is from @domain.tld, send an custom auto-reply.
If there is an email sent to important@subdomain.domain.tld, and the sender is not from @domain.tld, send an custom auto-reply and forward the mail to important@newdomain.tld
If there is an email sent to @subdomain.domain.tld, send an auto-reply with a generic "this user/e-mail-address does not exists"-message.
If there is en email sent to @subdomain.domain.tld, drop it.

The list of valid-users contains about 50 users, and will not grow. At the moment it's a plain text-file. Are Postfix able to do this task? If so, are there any good examples or guides?
I have no problem changing from Postfix to another MTA which may be better suited for this task.

product recommendations are off topic here. There is [softwarerecs.se] for that.

but this domain will soon cease to exist - I take it you are looking for an interim solution before the domain ceases to exist? Why can't Postfix do what you want? Did you try?

@GeraldSchneider, the intention was not software recommendations, but how to configure an MTA to do this task. Have edited the question to better reflect the intention.

@JaromandaX, yes this will be an interim solution. I have tried to solve the problem with Postfix, but I have not succeed (yet). I am looking for a guide or examples, or at least a hint if Postfix are able to do the job or not.

If you want co configure your MTA, state what you are using, what is not working and provide your configuration so someone can help you with it. If you want to have a recommendation for an MTA it's, well, a recommendation. Nobody will write the whole configuration for you, we can only help you with concrete problems. If you want guides, google them.

Postfix able to do this task - yes, you may need a milter to do some of it, but, the answer is yes

It's easy to implement the logic you want in a script.
With Postfix I'd then setup a script-calling alias in /etc/aliases file, e.g. the one which starts with the pipe, for example:
important   |/usr/local/bin/autoreply.py

And redirect everything to that email using luser_relay in main.cf, for example:
mydestination = subdomain.domain.tld
luser_relay = important@subdomain.domain.tld
local_recipient_maps =

(this value of mydestination is needed for the important record in the aliases file to actually specify the address important@subdomain.domain.tld).

Or, the redirect thing can be done in a more safe (address-preserving) way with virtual alias maps. In that case, you still need a pipe-alias in the /etc/aliases, because it's the only place where it can happen, but instead of setting mydestination and others that way you set up virtual_alias_domains and virtual_alias_maps to redirect everything to that address. In that case, the script address must not be in that domain. E.g., in main.cf:
virtual_alias_domains = subdomain.domain.tld
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
mydestination = another.subdomain.domain.tld

and that file, /etc/postfix/virtual would contain:
@subdomain.domain.tld  important@another.subdomain.domain.tld

The destination here has to match user part in aliases file and domain name in mydestination, which, in turn, must not include subdomain.domain.tld itself.
